# c# Serial Port Data is ineffective

Tags: c#, serial-port

This data I got from the RS232 cable is another program that lights up the LED. I want to light the LED again by transmitting this data, which we received by reverse engineering, over the serial port, but there is no response.
What could be the solution for this?

[image]

**Received Data Code:**

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
      string newLine = Environment.NewLine;
      string buffer = "";
      buffer=serialPort1.ReadExisting();
    
     // var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(buffer);
     // var decoded = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes);

       txtReceived.Text = txtReceived.Text + buffer;
       txtReceived.Text = txtReceived.Text + serialPort1.ReadExisting();
       txtReceived.Select(txtReceived.Text.Length, 0);

    }
```

**Transmit Data code:**

```
        private void btnGonder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  //Send Button
    {
        try
        {
            if (serialPort1 == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Check COM ");
            }
            else
            {
                string strToUni = txtSendedCommand.Text;
                byte[] buf = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(strToUni);
                serialPort1.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);


                //var decoded = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes);
               
                txtSendedCommand.Clear();
                lstBxDurum.Items.Add("Data is send.");
                // txtReceived.Text = "\n";

            }

        }
        catch
        {
            lstBxDurum.Items.Add("Warning!Data is not sended.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check `SerialPort` settings: baudrate, various bits, handshaking - all should match. `serialPort1.Write` doesn't guarantee delivery.

Comment: @Sinatr When I checked all the settings, I couldn't find any difference.